Arduino nano ESP32 crash unknown cause
First time posting on and I'm also pretty new to coding in general.
Here is the issue:
I wrote up some code for a Arduino Uno R4 to send a UDP packet every minute to 4 Arduino Nano esp32-s3s. the Nanos should return the UDP request with a packet containing temp and humidity read from a sensor. the code runs fine for the first 13 or so minutes and then the Nano freeze.
The Arduino Uno R4 just sends a packet every minute to the Nano. The entire contents of the packet is "Temp?".
A couple odd things I've noticed is that the freeze often occurs between UDP requests. This leads me to think that whatever the issue is it isn't happening with the handling of the UPD packet.
Things I have checked.

Memory leaks. Printed out available stack and heap every time a UDP request was sent and no change request to request.
Networking issue. Confirmed that UDP requests were still being sent with my router. Also the serial printout wouldn't freeze as well.
Faulty equipment. Verified that the same issue was occurring on the other Nanos.

I'm kind of at a dead end so any help would be appreciated.
#include <DHT11.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

int CNT = 0;
int ID = 2;
DHT11 dht11(2);
char SSID[] = "IOT";
char pass[] = "SSN690am!";
unsigned int localPort = 2390; 
char packetBuffer[255];
char qryTemp[] = "Temp?";
WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {
    // Initialize serial communication to allow debugging and data readout.
    // Using a baud rate of 9600 bps.
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
    WiFi.begin(SSID, pass);
    Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
    int temp = 0;
    int humidity = 0;
    int result = dht11.readTemperatureHumidity(temp, humidity);
    
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  Serial.print(packetSize);

  if (packetSize) {
    Serial.printf("\nStack:%d,Heap:%lu\n", uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL), (unsigned long)ESP.getFreeHeap());

    Serial.print("MSG COUNT:");
    Serial.println(CNT);
    CNT++;

    Serial.print("Received packet of size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");
    Serial.print(Udp.remoteIP());
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());

    // read the packet into packetBufffer

    int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);
    if (len > 0) {
      packetBuffer[len] = 0;
    }

    Serial.println("Contents:");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer);

    if(int(packetBuffer[0]) == 84 and int(packetBuffer[1]) == 101 and int(packetBuffer[2]) == 109 and int(packetBuffer[3]) == 112 and int(packetBuffer[4]) == 63){

    // send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received

    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());

    Udp.write(char(ID));
    Udp.write(char(temp));
    Udp.write(char(humidity));

    Udp.endPacket();
    Udp.flush();
    }
  }
}


Problem solved:
Something about querying the Dht11 sensor every loop for a temp and humidity value was causing the freeze. I am guessing that it was overloading the I2C bus and causing a crash.
Either way when the code is changed to only query the sensor when a UDP request is received fixed the issue.
